# IE8 doesn't show second custom font

Tags: css, fonts, internet-explorer-8, font-face

I have two custom fonts on my webpage, one loads perfectly, the other sadly doesn't.

I built my font files with http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ which usually always works.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'cartoonistkooky';
    src: url('#{$fontsDir}cartoonist_kooky-webfont.eot');
    src: url('#{$fontsDir}cartoonist_kooky-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('#{$fontsDir}cartoonist_kooky-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('#{$fontsDir}cartoonist_kooky-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('#{$fontsDir}cartoonist_kooky-webfont.svg#cartoonistkooky') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'hastypudding';
    src: url('#{$fontsDir}hasty_pudding-webfont.eot');
    src: url('#{$fontsDir}hasty_pudding-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('#{$fontsDir}hasty_pudding-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('#{$fontsDir}hasty_pudding-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('#{$fontsDir}hasty_pudding-webfont.svg#hasty_puddingregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Cartooniskooky is not displaying in IE8, also no errors.

Comment: Please show the URL so that all of the CSS and HTML code can be accessed and it can be verified what the server sends when the font files are requested for. This could be simply a typo in the font file name, or something more complicated.

Comment: there is only partial support for @gont-face in IE8. Check here: http://caniuse.com/#search=font-face Can you post an example of this not working?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela can't do that, site is under construction and data is not public yet